# Error in using setBackground( new Color(0,0,0,0)) in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Firstly, I make some panels overlap each other and setVisible for them when click. Everything goes fine until I use `setBackGround(new Color(0,0,0,0))` for all panels to make them look like transparent, but `setVisible(false)` does not work, meaning that the current panel is still shown with others. It looks like:

[image]

Comment: We need a small self contained example of this. I'm not clear on the issue. It is possible it can be fixed by using javax.swing.JComponent.setOpaque(false)

Comment: @Adam thank you so much i just set it false and it goes fine :)

Comment: No worries, I've written up as a answer

Comment: Swing doesn't support alpha based colors for component backgrounds

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with not setting `setOpaque(false)`.

See [JComponent.setOpaque()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque-boolean-)

This is alluded to in the JavaDoc for [JComponent.setBackground](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground-java.awt.Color-)

> Sets the background color of this component. The background color is
>   used only if the component is **opaque**, and only by subclasses of
>   JComponent or ComponentUI implementations. Direct subclasses of
>   JComponent must override paintComponent to honor this property.